# a pointer bound to a function may only be used to call a function

Tags: c++, pointers, stdstring

I've just moved from char arrays to std::string and I've already ran into a problem, I'm probably doing something extremely stupid, feel free to ridicule:

```
int main()
{
    string * p = new string;
    memset(p, 0, sizeof(string));

    expected_exepath(p);

    cout << p->data;

    delete p;
}
```

The error is in p->data, which says "a pointer bound to a function may only be used to call a function".. p is std::string, so I don't see why it thinks I'm trying to call a function.

Comment: What is `expected_exepath`? Ridicule: Just say `int main() { string p; expected_exepath(p); cout << p; }`. You should try and unthink the expression `new` out of your C++ mindset. It is almost never needed or in good taste in client-side code.

Comment: Probably expected_exepath takes a char* buffer that the OP was trying to fill.  Just a guess....

Comment: I'm new to C++ so I'm just trying things out but thanks for the tip. expected_exepath takes std::string *.

Comment: Why does `expected_exepath take `std::string *`?  Sounds like it should just return a string, and take no arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because data is a *function*, not a data member. More importantly, half the point of `std::string` is that it's a value. You shouldn't use `new` unless you have an extremely good reason- allocate on the stack, or if you must dynamically allocate use a container or smart pointer.

Also: Do not ever, ever, ever memset UDTs like that. They take care of their own internal state, all the time, and do not mess with it.

Comment: I know I'm not allocating a whole map of a video game or something, but I'm just trying things out. I wasn't thinking; too used to char arrays.

Answer (score 7):

> The error is in p->data, which says "a pointer bound to a function may
>   only be used to call a function".. p is std::string, so I don't see
>   why it thinks I'm trying to call a function.

A few points:

- `string::data()` is a function, hence that error message is entirely appropriate.
- `p` is a *pointer* to a `std::string`, not an `std::string`.
- Passing `p->data()` to `cout` would be dangerous given that `data()` returns a char array without a null terminator, unlike `string::c_str()`. I'd suggest you just use

  ```
  cout << *p;
  ```

  ...instead.

If `expected_exepath` takes a `std::string*` argument, then I'd suggest re-writing your function like this:

```
int main()
{
    string p;    
    expected_exepath(&p); 
    cout << p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << p->data;
```

`string::data()` is a function, not a data member. You need to call it, not just dereference it. Like this:

```
cout << p->data();
```

Comment: Great, thanks I didn't realize that. Perhaps I should look at documentation next time

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to provide another possible mistake that cause the same error message although not related to your specific question.

It's when you use `vector.emplace_back{.. , ..}` instead of `vector.emplace_back(.. , ..)`.

Hope maybe someone making this mistake like me does not get confused for hours.

Comment: I made the same mistake and it cost me only 10 minutes to find your answer. Big +1 :-)